# How can I fix CDF Windowsize as constant

Tags: windows

I want to make `CDF` `WindowSize` as constant so that the end user can not resize it either by dragging Window or by maximizing it.

Is there any in built `Mathematica` function to do this?

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you are producing stand alone CDF to be opened on a computer, and *not* a web page embedded version to be opened via plugin?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: yes, I am asking about stand alone CDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it by removing `"ResizeArea"` element from `WindowFrameElements` option of the CDF file.

For example, we generate a resizable standalone CDF and open it in Mathematica:

```
cdfpath = CDFDeploy[
  ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory}, "thisistest.cdf"],
  Manipulate[n!, {n, 1, 10, 1}],
  WindowSize -> {400, 200},
  Method -> "Standalone"];

nb = NotebookOpen[cdfpath];
```

Then we remove the `"ResizeArea"` element and save it:

```
SetOptions[nb, WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ZoomBox"}]
NotebookSave[nb]
```

Note the changing at the lower right corner. Now the window size of `nb` should be fixed.

[image]

**Caution**

As @VitaliyKaurov warned in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-can-i-fix-cdf-windowsize-as-constant#comment25999_9043), the `WindowFrameElements` has a long-term hidden danger as [the official document said](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WindowFrameElements.html):

> This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Mathematica system, and is subject to change.

So please use it with vigilance.

Comment: A word of caution from documentation center about "WindowFrameElements": "This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Mathematica system, and is subject to change." ( http://bit.ly/QykM7T )

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes I'm aware of it. But as I don't know how long exactly does "long-term" mean, I'd like to use it for good flexibility when custom notebooks. But yes! it's a hidden danger, I'll add a caution in my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @Silvia: Is it possible to minimise the window size upto an extent and not after that? so that the end user can only have an option of increasing the window size.

Comment: @Jennifer didn't figure out a handy method, but I think it's possible. Maybe some `Dynamic` things are needed in `WindowSize` option along with something like `Dynamic[CurrentValue["WindowSize"]]`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to be careful. For example deploying large enough content of fixed window size would create problems on small computer screens. That warning being said, this is what you can do.

Imagine this is your interactive content:

```
m = Manipulate[Plot[Sin[f x]/x/f, {x, -6.6, 6.6}, PlotRange -> {-.3, 1}, Filling -> 0],
     {{f, 4, "frequency"}, 1, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

You can take advantage of dialog-type of Mathematica notebook using **`CreateDialog` which by default always makes the window not-re-sizable**. Then use programmatic deployment with function `CDFDeploy`:

```
CDFDeploy["Standalone.cdf", CreateDialog[{m}, WindowSize -> All],Method -> "Standalone"]
```

This will create **Standalone.cdf** CDF file in your default directory which you can find by running `Directory[]`. This is what you will get:

[image]

The [**WindowSize**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WindowSize.html) is very important, so you should read corresponding documentation articled that I linked. One of the most handy settings, besides fixed size, is actually scaled with respect to screen size settings. To Make a window that occupies one-third of the screen width and all of the screen height:

```
WindowSize -> {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the output of the Manipulate in [Panel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Panel.html).

This should enable you to use `ImageSize` and control the size of the `CDF` pretty well.

See the documentation:

[image]

This will enable you to control the size of the CDF within the CDF Window.

To better control the size of the notebook window itself look at the option inspector:

[image]

and the `WindowSize` setting.